# Quantile lines of stationary process

Tags: stochastic-processes, simulation, stationary-processes

Quantile lines of any stationary process are parallel and constant. But for different procesess I've obtained different behavior of quantile lines. First case was process after Lamperti transormation of alpha-stable motion. In that case quantile lines are parallel from the beginning. The second case was Orstein-Uhlenbeck process(simulated from stochastic differential equation), which is stationaty and I've obtained quantile lines which becomes parallel after some time. Why am I observing such behavior?